# EditText multiline, not editable but selectable

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

I need a multi-line `EditText` where users can only select and copy text, but not edit it.

I tried this way:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextHelp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|none"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:maxLength="2000"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" >
</EditText>
```

However, it seems like `textMultiLine|none` doesn't work. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TextView instead

```
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editTextHelp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:longClickable="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use and TextView instead of EditText as following if its just for show some text:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

But if you want to disable the textinput and maintain multi line perhaps you should try a programmatically approach like these:

```
    editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

please read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) for more info

Comment: and where is  multi-line ?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    />
```

Comment: and where is multi-line ?